# Sign of the line integral ($\int_{\vert z\vert=1} {1 \over z^2} \tan({\pi \over z}) dz$)

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find the value of the $$\int_{\vert z\vert=1} {1 \over z^2} \tan\left({\pi \over z}\right) dz$$

When we substitute $\omega = {1 \over z}$, then $d\omega = - {1 \over z^2}dz$, hence  $\int_{\vert z\vert=1} {1 \over z^2} \tan({\pi \over z}) dz = -\int_{\vert \omega \vert=1}  $$\tan({\omega \pi}) d\omega = -4i$. (By Either residue thm on $\pm {1 \over 2}$ or argument principle).

But the problem is the answer was $4i$

Why does the sign have to be positive?

Comment: I think the contour orientation may switch with the substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{\vert z\vert=1} {1 \over z^2} tan({\pi \over z}) dz = \int_{\vert \omega \vert=1}  $$tan({\omega \pi}) d\omega $. Use the definition of contour integral to justify the formula I have written.

Comment: I'd say a change of variables works exactly the same, both are line integrals. The issue is that when you refer to an integral over $|z| = 1$ or over $[a, b]$, neither is well-defined until you specify the implicit assumptions you're using to choose the direction in which the contour is traversed.